# SQLAlchemy Core: order by desc

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

What is the proper way to execute a select statement with an "ORDER BY foo DESC" in SQLAlchemy core? (**core, not ORM!**)

I'm currently including the direction in the `order_by` directly:

```
mytable.select(order_by='name DESC')
```

...it works (although I don't like it since it's a little bit "hackish"), but SQLAlchemy gives me the following warning:

> SAWarning: Can't resolve label reference 'name DESC'; converting to
>   text() (this warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)
>   util.ellipses_string(element.element))

(I didn't find anything about in [the doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select))

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc):

```
from sqlalchemy import desc

stmt = select([users_table]).order_by(desc(users_table.c.name))
```

Comment: To be fair, the core docs are a little trickier to find, as the ORM is vastly more popular ;)

Comment: yep... the problem is also that SQLAlchemy is really an huge project and there are even several ways of accomplish the same thing :P

Comment: Indeed. But once you get over a certain threshold of knowledge then it's pretty easy to find the things that you're looking for. Also, if my answer solved your problem you can mark it accepted ;)

Answer (score 6):

Or according to [the same documentation link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc):

```
stmt = users_table.select().order_by(users_table.c.name.desc())
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort column by asc/desc

```
desc = " " + asc_desc
order_by = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '', order_by) + desc
query = query.order_by(text(order_by)) 
return query
```